# How to create an index column, every 7 occurrences in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `pyspark` dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'date_col':['2010-02-27','2010-01-20','2010-01-20','2010-01-21','2010-01-21','2010-02-21','2010-02-22','2010-02-23','2010-02-24','2010-02-25','2010-02-26','2010-01-20','2010-01-21','2010-02-20'], 'group':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b']})
```

I would like to create a `week` column, which would be an index, which increases every 7 ordered unique values of the `date_col` by `group`.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'date_col':['2010-02-27','2010-01-20','2010-01-20','2010-01-21','2010-01-21','2010-02-21','2010-02-22','2010-02-23','2010-02-24','2010-02-25','2010-02-26','2010-01-20','2010-01-21','2010-02-20'], 'group':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b'],
               'week':[2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

Any ideas could I do that in `pyspark`?

**UPDATE**

Some more explanation on the logic.

Basically the operation could be split into the following steps:

1. Order the `foo` on `date_col` grouped by `group`
2. Create a `temp_index` column, which would rank the `date_col` by `group`
3. Create a `week` column which would be the `div` of `temp_index` with `7`

Comment: The logic is unclear. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @mck edited the question to add logic steps on how the result could be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` and divide the rank by 7. You need to subtract 1 before dividing because in SQL, ranks start from 1 rather than 0.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'week', 
    (
        (F.dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('date_col')) - 1) / 7
    ).cast('int')
)

df2.show()
+----------+-----+----+
|  date_col|group|week|
+----------+-----+----+
|2010-01-20|    b|   0|
|2010-01-21|    b|   0|
|2010-02-20|    b|   0|
|2010-01-20|    a|   0|
|2010-01-20|    a|   0|
|2010-01-21|    a|   0|
|2010-01-21|    a|   0|
|2010-02-21|    a|   0|
|2010-02-22|    a|   0|
|2010-02-23|    a|   0|
|2010-02-24|    a|   0|
|2010-02-25|    a|   0|
|2010-02-26|    a|   1|
|2010-02-27|    a|   1|
+----------+-----+----+
```